# Static home page ignored

Tags: php, customization, plugin-polylang

I am trying to show an static page instead of posts. It is defined accordingly in Settings-Reading, and it works fine. It uses a front-page template. But activating Polylang (since my web should be in several languages) causes a posts list to appear in home page, ignoring the setting of an static page, and using an index.php template.

I have read posts on that situation but definitely I am not seeing the clue. I would like to trace where WP takes the decision, but I am not proficient enough in debugging.

I would like to have some guidance to trace this behaviour or see what I am doing wrong.

thanks

Comment: Hi Santiago, welcome to WPSE. Please feel free to [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site. It sounds like the Polylang plugin might not honour that setting, in which case it might be worth asking [at their support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/polylang). In regards to what you have read already, could you perhaps edit your question to add in some more details about what hasn't worked for you, so people here don't rehash the same things? Thanks!

Comment: @Santiago Just copy your index.php file and give it name as `home.php`. Then in home.php paste all code of your static home page. Make sure to put `<?php get_header();?>` on top and `<?php get_footer();?>` on bottom in home.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting that the static page you intend to show is a static page for the home page of your site. If that's the case, and the static page is truly static, I recommend saving the page as index.html and saving it (via ftp) right next to your WP index.php file in the root folder of your domain.

The .html file will be served up before the .php file, always, and *boom* now you've got a static home page.